# Set Text for interpolation in html

Tags: angular, ionic2, interpolation

Hi does anyone know how to set a dynamic value for the {{buttonText}}.

I wish to do it in a such a way that when there is no more article to show , the {{buttonText}} will display as "Show Less".

**My Html**

```
<button ion-item (click)="items.showMore2 = !items.showMore2; items.showMore1 = !items.showMore1; items.toggleMore2 = !items.toggleMore2; items.toggleMore1 = !items.toggleMore1" [hidden]="items.toggleMore1" text-center detail-none large>
  <h4 class="showMoreText"><ion-icon name="arrow-down" *ngIf="!items.arrow"></ion-icon>
  <ion-icon name="arrow-up" *ngIf="items.arrow"></ion-icon> {{buttonText}}</h4>
</button>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You know you assign the value inside the component right? Your question is a little unclear

Answer (score 1):

At first I would suggest to look at the [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#interpolation) guide of interpolation, because these are really the basics of angular. Just take a dive into that website, and read the guides and cookbooks to get the hang of the basics of angular.

You can set a variable inside your `@Component` class:

```
@Component({
   template: `<div>{{buttonText}}</div>
})
export class AppComponent {

  public buttonText: string = "test";

}
```

Any variable/method defined inside your component, can be used inside your template

Comment: Hi but is there a way to do assign the string value in html instead of typescript as i'm trying to do a dynamic change text.

Comment: Make a bigger example in your question as to what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

```
{{buttonText}}

export class App{
   buttonText:string="test";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing a variable in your template is possible, but you will need any event for it.

```html
<div>
  <h2 (click)="name = 'test'">Hello {{name}}</h2> <!-- simple -->
  <h2 (click)="name = names[(index = ((index + 1) % names.length))]">Hello {{name}}</h2> <!-- expert -->
</div>
```

live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/SePBxTOvOKlSE2gQ8Xi2?p=preview